# xml schema declaration type

Tags: xml, schema

i have created a XML schema like below:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="fruitName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="fruitCategory" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="fruitColor" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="farm">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="fruitName"/>
            <xs:element ref="fruitCategory"/>
            <xs:element ref="fruitColor"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="farmLocation" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="farmAge" type="xs:Integer" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

from my understanding, i believe that this is using fully global type declaration XML schema as the element of fruitName,fruitCategory and fruitColor is declared globally and being called by using ref="" in the complex type.Please tell me whether this schema is created fully using global declaration type or i have misunderstood what global declaration type is.If i am wrong, please advise how should i code it correctly using fully global type declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The schema seems fine except for the extra closing attribute tag:

```
</xs:attribute>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the term "fully global type declaration XML schema", but I would have imagined it to mean a schema in which all the type declarations are global. This is clearly not the case with your schema, since the only complex type declared is an anonymous type embedded within an element declaration. However, it's a valid schema.